# Spring boot App - .war welcome file list config

Tags: spring-boot

I use Spring boot embedded container and it works fine. Now, moving to war file deployment duo to some restriction on .jar with webapp folder. Not sure how to configure welcome file list with Spring boot war.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing default welcome-page for spring-boot application deployed as a war](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26057995/changing-default-welcome-page-for-spring-boot-application-deployed-as-a-war)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Perhaps this answer could be of assistance

> [Changing default welcome-page for spring-boot application deployed as a war](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26057995/changing-default-welcome-page-for-spring-boot-application-deployed-as-a-war)