# Spring MVC home page

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have HomeController class:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String showPage() {
        return "main-menu";
    }
}
```

My project structure:
[image]

Spring version: 4.3.9
web.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.form</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

</beans>
```

---

It always shows index.jsp, never main-menu.jsp
I want a main-menu my Home Page. What should i do?

Comment: spring by default takes index.jsp, index.html etc as the welcome pages. this feature can be disabed as per this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/29054676/3981536

Comment: so i can't set home page with other name?

Comment: you can, but you need to override the default behaviour of spring

Comment: also verify in the spring startup logs, if the request endpoint is registered..

Comment: show us `dispatcher-servlet.xml` and `web.xml`

Comment: remove pages from  `<welcome-file-list>` in web.xml

Comment: just added dispatcher-servlet.xml and web.xml to post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i've used an approach to solve this problem in my project. 
i'm sharing it with you below
Keep only below content in your index.jsp

```
index.jsp

<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=welcome" />
```

In your controller java program the `RequestMapping` must hold the value specified in the `url` attribute of `<meta>` tag specified in `index.jsp` file. 
In this example, the `url` attribute has value `welcome`

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/welcome")
    public String welcome() {
        return "main-menu";
    }
}
```

This worked for me

**Updated #1:**

```
    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

**Updated #2:**

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="add your base folder here" />
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. IDE always says "No view resolvers found"

Comment: do you have viewResolver defined in yourdispatcher-servlet.xml?

Comment: No, look at dispatcher-servlet.xml in post

Comment: @Raspberry i have updated the code for view resolver in the answer.verify it

Comment: @Raspberry place the main-menu.jsp inside the pages folder in case if you are following the same code i have posted

Comment: ok, i added that bean to dispatcher-servlet.xml, IDE now found main-menu.jsp, but when i run project i have 404 error on http://localhost:8081/welcome

Comment: @Raspberry you need to add some entries in dispatcher-servlet.xml for scanning the annotations for autoconfig. i think you didnot add those and that is causing the trouble. Check my updated #2 answer

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in your `web.xml` file:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.form</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

You declare to the servlet container that SpringMVC `DispatcherServlet` will only process URL ending in `.form`. So the request for home never reaches SpringMVC machinery - BTW, that also explains why divine's proposal of `/welcome` does not work either, but `/welcome.form` should...

You could also have a look to this other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26325525/3545273) from mine for a general discussion of how to process the root URL with SpringMVC.

Answer (score 0):

---

Briefly your web application will look into `welcome page` and `/directMe` is invoked which is captured by `controller` class and execute the logic you have implemented.

Add this in `web.xml`

```
 <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
```

In the `JSP` itself, add below coding:

```
<c:redirect url="/directMe"/>
```

Lastly, in the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/directMe", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String myMethod(HttpServletRequest servletRequest, HttpServletResponse servletResponse) throws IOException { 
// add your logic to execute
        return "main-menu"; // returns main-menu page with your logic
}
```