# How do you configure the Spring Boot application to return a different HTML file when the '#' character appears in the URL?

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

I have an application written in AngularJS. It is quite "heavy", so I separated the start page to the static page without all dependencies.

**So I have two main files:**

- index.html (start page)
- app.html (angular application)

My start page has this URL:
`http://localhost:8080/`

The question is - how to set up a Spring Boot so that my `AngularJS` application will be available at url: `http://localhost:8080/#/login`

Comment: change welcomepage with spring boot configuration
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26057995/changing-default-welcome-page-for-spring-boot-application-deployed-as-a-war/29054676

Comment: @Gurkanİlleez My welcome page is index.html and I do not want to change it. I want to return different page when # appears.

Comment: Your angular application is single page application right?

Comment: Also you have bootstrap js or typescript file

Comment: In Spring Boot static sources served but if you have permission problem maybe you can change the spring security part. Which error do you get?

Comment: `Your angular application is single page application right?` Yes. If I rename my app.html file to index.html, I will be able to use my application by entering AngularJS states names (for example: http//localhost:8080/#/login, http//localhost:8080/#/dashboard). But - I want to have it in index.html.