# How to make default url to be viewed in browser in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, swagger

I have a microservice developed using **Spring Boot 2.1.3** version and also I have used SpringFox version 2.9.2 for Swagger documentation. Every time when I distribute or deploy to third party or any other person, I have to always mention the swagger url for the user to go through the REST end-points.  My question is how to make a default redirected url in case of spring boot so that **it should redirect to swagger-ui.html** automatically. It means if the user types http://localhost:8080 in the browser, the browser should automatically redirect to the url ie. **http://localhost:8080/api/swagger-ui.html**. I want to know is there any configuration required for this ?

Before reaching to stackoverflow, I have gone through the following links and tried, but nothing worked as expected.

[Java Spring Boot: How to map my app root (“/”) to index.html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27381781/java-spring-boot-how-to-map-my-app-root-to-index-html/27383522)

[Changing default welcome-page for spring-boot application deployed as a war](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26057995/changing-default-welcome-page-for-spring-boot-application-deployed-as-a-war)

I tried different ways also, but I always get 404 or Whitelabel Error Page. I want to know is there any way in case whitelabel error page it should automatically redirect to swagger page ie. **http://localhost:8080/api/swagger-ui.html**.

I have also added the below in application.properties.

```
server.servlet.context-path=/api
```

Please help me in this regard.

Answer (score 10):

You could add a RedirectViewController like this:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addRedirectViewController("/", "/api/swagger-ui.html");
    }

}
```

Comment: I have already tried this option, I have also mentioned in the post. It is not working.

Comment: than maybe you should check your configuration, in a blank application this will work ..

Comment: I tried this, but somehow my https request is going to http URL

Answer (score 3):

Your controller should like below:

```
@RestController
public class DefaultController implements ErrorController {

    @Override
    public String getErrorPath() {
        return "/error";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/error")
    public void handleErrorWithRedirect(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        response.sendRedirect("/swagger-ui.html");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public void redirect(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        response.sendRedirect("/swagger-ui.html");
    }

}
```

I also have put together a working model for you in my [github](https://github.com/amithkumarg/restapi-springboot-jpa) spring-boot project.

For default/index page or error page, it will always redirect to `swagger-ui.html`.
Let me know if you still have questions.

Comment: Hi Amith, I took your code checked,It does not work as per my question. Can you try http://localhost:8080/ in the browser ? Does it redirect to swagger page ?It does not work for me. We can handle error page in a way.

Comment: If you look into application.properties file, I have this setting `# ****** WebServer *******
server.servlet.context-path=/
server.port=3007`, so instead of 8080 if you use localhost:3007, it will work. You can change those properties as per your need.

Comment: Hi Amith, if you give server.servlet.context-path=/api in application.properties, it does not work. Think that api is the name of the microservice where customer does not know. Customer simply types localhost:8080/, it should redirect to the url which I have mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

You can use  a Controller for your default path

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public String index(Model model) {            
    return "redirect: /api/swagger-ui.html";
```

}

Comment: take a look here hope you will find solution https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#getting-started.changing-base-uri

Comment: @debadatta-mishra, you'll need to either delete your `server.servlet.context-path=/api` or you'll have to hit `localhost:8080/api` for this redirect to work.

Based on your question though, it looks like you _really_ don't want that `server.servlet.context-path` property set, because then your web service is *only* accessible from `/api/`, and never just `/`

Comment: @Bwvolleyball, I have already tried these options, nothing worked.